# How does the Error object seems to create properties on itself by his own on Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Ok I'd first like to say that I know there's probably a very basic explanation for this, so excuse me if this is a way too newbie kind of question.

**The question is:**
How come the Error.message property doesn't exist until I create a new prototype?

Example:

```
let a = new Error('testing')
console.log( a.message ) // 'testing'
```

But before if I tried to access the Error properties and methods (e.g: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Error)`) the message property wouldn't even be there, not even an empty string, it just wouldn't exist.

Shouldn't it have been an empty string before? How does the Error object creates a new property on its own when a new prototype is created?

Comment: `getOwnPropertyNames` only returns properties set *on* an object, not inherited (prototype) properties. The clue is in the name: "**own**"-properties.

Comment: What do you mean by "*when a new prototype is created*"?

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Error)` will only list the **static** members of the `Error` constructor function. If you do `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Error.prototype )` then you'll see thme.

Comment: How do you think `const a = {message: "testing"}` creates a new property on the new object without the property existing on any prototype before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getOwnPropertyNames` only returns properties set *on* an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames), not inherited (prototype) properties. The clue is in the name: "**own**"-properties.

By example:

```
const a_simple_object_with_no_prototype = {
    b: "b",
    c: "c"
};

console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyNames( a_simple_object_with_no_prototype ) )
// [ "b", "c" ]
```

With an object with properties inherited from a prototype we get different results:

```
const an_object_used_as_a_prototype = {
    a: 789
};

function ConstructorFunction() {
    this.b = "b";
}
ConstructorFunction.prototype = an_object_used_as_a_prototype;

const an_object_with_a_prototype = new ConstructorFunction();
an_object_with_a_prototype.c = "c";


console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyNames( an_object_with_a_prototype ) )
// [ "b", "c" ] // does not include "a" which is inherited from the prototype
```

> But before if I tried to access the Error properties and methods (e.g: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Error)`) the message property wouldn't even be there, not even an empty string, it just wouldn't exist.

That's because `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Error)` will only list the "static"[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) members of the `Error` constructor function. If you do `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Error.prototype )` then you'll see them:

```
const protoProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Error.prototype );
console.log( protoProps ); // ["constructor", "name", "message", "toString"]
```

I do note that the `Error` object in JavScript is imbued with some *special* behaviour which you cannot replicate in JavaScript itself, such as how its `stack` property works, but that's outside the scope of your question.

[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames): I use the term "static" in the C++ / Java / C# sense in that it's a field/member that is associated with a *type* rather than an *instance*. It does not mean the property/field/member is unchanging, readonly, nor immutable.